# How to statistical analyze a discrete variable which is not necessary for an event to occur but which favours it?

Tags: chi-squared-test, multivariate-analysis, discrete-data

I am trying to assess if a quantitative discrete variable has an impact in the occurrence of an event. However, I am aware that this variable is not necessary for the event to occur, because it also can be affected by other variables (which I cannot measure).

My hypothesis is that higher values of my variable favour the occurrence of the event. However, as there are other variables (which I cannot measure) affecting the event, there are also going to be occurrences of the event with low values of this variable.

At first I was thinking about dividing the data into two groups using a threshold value for this quantitative variable and checking its impact on the event with a Fisher or Chi2 test, by creating a table like this:

```
                 High   Low
Occurrence        50     55
Not occurrence    5      40
```

However, I am not sure if this approach is correct. Do you know how can analyze this hypothesis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your data, the dependent variable is ordinal. By making this binary high/low you lose the possibility of discovering something like a dose-response effect. This is the biological gradient numbered five of nine here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradford_Hill_criteria.

Also, if you make that variable binary, unless you have a biological plausible a priori value, then the chi-squared result will depend on the threshold. For example a very large threshold will likely give a low p-value if your hypothesis is correct, so your ability to find a “good” threshold will affect things.

One way forward would be ordinal logistic regression, and then other variables could be added as dependent variables, as biological variables often do not act alone. With logistic regression, odds ratios can be useful in interpreting the results.

Comment: I see your point. I have also thought about a multiple regression taking into account the other variables, but it is not viable to measure them. So, I will check the logistic regression. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Categorizing an ordinal or continuous variable will lead to an invalid uninterpretable analysis that is also inefficient---a triple loss.  If time is irrelevant, i.e., if the event you are studying is assessed over a very short time period, then use binary logistic regression to predict it from the quantitative variable, expanding the quantitative  variable so as to not assume linearity in its effect on the log odds.  To do this consider a quadratic polynomial or a regression spline.  The choice will depend on subject matter knowledge and knowledge of the distribution of the potential predictor variable.

Comment: Do you think a quadratic polynomial is appropiate taking into account that my dependent variable is a factor?

Comment: Quadratic for an independent variable.  Ordinal logistic regression optimally handles a continuous or ordinal dependent variable.